# Cabal-installed Modules won't import

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

There are several things I'm confused about here, so I'll try to explain each of them as clearly as I can.

I've been trying to install the `diagrams` package for haskell, using cabal. [I've seen it suggested](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html#developing-with-sandboxes) to install packages using sandboxes, so that's what I did. Something that's not clear to me is exactly what a sandbox is - I understand that I can initialise one with `cabal sandbox init` and install packages inside of it with `cabal install`, but I don't see how to use those packages once they're installed.

I then tried to compile a test-script using ghc, which resulted in the following error:

```
diagramstutorial.lhs:3:10:
    Could not find module 'Diagrams.Prelude'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

With a similar error for another module that the script was supposed to load. These modules are definitely both included in the diagrams package, and cabal seems happy that the package is installed correctly. I expect there's something simple I just don't understand, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: How did you try to compile test-script using ghc ? What command did you gave ? Where you inside the sandboxed directory at that time ?

Comment: I was in the same directory as the sandbox, and I typed 'ghc --make diagramstutorial.lhs' to compile it (that was the title of the file)

Comment: Closely related: [Installed parsec in sandbox, but can't find libraries when trying to load file in ghci](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23120611/installed-parsec-in-sandbox-but-cant-find-libraries-when-trying-to-load-file-i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I typed `ghc --make diagramstutorial.lhs` to compile it

That will make GHC use the regular user package database (that is, not the sandbox one). Use `cabal exec -- ghc --make diagramstutorial.lhs` instead, so that GHC runs in the context of your sandbox.

You can also use GHCi within the sandbox with `cabal repl`. And naturally, if/when you start preparing a cabal package, all cabal commands (`cabal build`, etc.) will use the sandbox if you are within its directory.

> Something that's not clear to me is exactly what a sandbox is

A set of packages with an accompanying database local to the directory. Beyond the `cabal.sandbox.config` configuration file there is also a hidden directory `.cabal-sandbox`, in which `diagrams` and the other packages you installed lie.

Comment: This is only true for Cabal 1.20 and onwards. For older versions see my reply below which is a global solution and should be preferred.

Comment: Something confusing has happened... This advice worked fine yesterday, but now I get the error `cabal.exe: unrecognised command: exec (try --help)`. Do you know what might have happened?

Comment: @DanielLittlewood What does `cabal --version` tell you? As Arnon pointed out, `cabal exec` was added in the 1.20 version. Is it possible that you are using an older version of cabal today? (That is not as implausible as it sounds, given that `cabal install cabal-install` will perform a local, and not system-wide, installation of the cabal program.)

Comment: Aha I see! Yes, that's the problem, I didn't know cabal would install itself locally as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the sandbox directory, and locate the `packages.conf.d` file.
   For example, `/home/user/.cabal-sandbox/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.8.4-packages.conf.d`
2. Rerun your GHC commands with the `package-db` flag:

   `ghci -package-db /home/user/.cabal-sandbox/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.8.4-packages.conf.d --make diagramstutorial.lhs`

Everything should now work